# Unindo doisdata frames pelos eixos

Tags: python, pandas

Sou principiante no estudo da programação e estou com uma dúvida:

Preciso unir dois dataframes pela coluna da data. Um data frame mostra informações sobre uma empresa que aluga bicicletas e outra as informações meteorológicas do dia.

O DF da empresa possuí muito mais linha e uma mesma data se repete diversas vezes, no outro é uma linha para cada data.

Poderiam me ajudar

Answer (score 1):

Opa...

eu uso o pd.merge, se as colunas nos dois dataframes são os mesmos utilizo "on".

```
import pandas as pd

pd.merge(df_1,df_2,on='data')
```

se os nomes são diferentes utilizo "left_on" e "right_on", ex:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.merge(df_1,df_2,left_on='data',right_on='data')
```

left_on para a coluna do dataframe da esquerda e right_on para a coluna do dataframe da direita.

Referencia: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html